# Have an error when I open HTML file in browser with visual studio

Tags: html, visual-studio-2015

When I click `open code by browser(chrome)` (I'm not sure if it is right translation. I use Korean version) button in `file` tab, a dialog pops up and says:

```
Can't complete the operation. Class is not applied
```

(either I'm not sure about this English expression) and don't work.
How can I fix this problem??

[clicking "open code by browser"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAtgT.png)

[dialog says "Can't complete the operation. Class is not applied"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgONJ.png)

Comment: what project type you have? can you open the file directly with the browser?

Comment: @tire0011, I'm not sure but maybe visual studio don't  provide HTML project. So I just made HTML file. And sure it works when I open it directly with the browser.

Comment: I have under file-->new-->new web site there you can open a empty asp.net web site and there edit your html pages. Currently you have no project oben because of that the open with browser will fail.

Comment: 'new website' don't work either. A dialog pops up and says that I should install 'web developer tool' before I  make one. And I tried to install that tool but I can't find way to do it. I think it was an option when I installed Visual Studio. Do you know how to??

Comment: Tools --> extensions and updates --> online --> search for it, from there you can install the tools